# does bufferedWriter require getters

Tags: java

Hi i know the use of getters is to restrict access. The issue is i have a buffered writer that is using some information in another class. Therefore using getters i have gotten that information and written into a file using the bufferedWriter.

The issue comes when i am trying to use some information in the same class as the bufferedWriter. It doesnt write those details . Shows no error in the code either just doesnt write it. If the data is in the same class as the buffered writer i assume that it doesnt need to be accessed using getters? although the values are stored in another method. Explain this
Thank you alot

```
 bufWrite.write("Your Character Class:" + character_Class + "\n");
    bufWrite.write("Your Character Level:" + level + "\n");
```

The character class and level here are from 1 class called character. To access these information i have used getters (Since the buffered writer is inside another class.Basically i have 3 classes. Character details in one and i am using the bufferedWriter which is in a different class to store these details into a file.)
These details are written into the file completely.

```
for(Object o:skillInfo){
            bufWrite.write("" + o + "-  Rank(skill Points) :" + rank);
        }
```

i am trying to use this foreach loop to write stuff inside a linkedlist. This linked list is inside the same class as the buffered writer statements are. But this doesnt get written while the other details(as listed above) get written. The only difference is that those details are using getters since they are not in the same class as the bufferedWriter is while the linked list is in the same as the bufferedWriter thus doesnt use a getter.

I hope this is clear enough

**Update

Also please note that the character.Level and the rank are user entered values.

Comment: Show use some code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Anjula, you are obviously a newbie Java coder, so instead of trying to guess what the root cause is and ask about that, please post the full details of your actual problem.

Comment: Hi @RobinGreen yes i am and at no point was i meaning to hide it the only reason i didnt post is since it is a group project that we are working on and the rest of the members are not keen on the information being posted on the internet. No other reason. Although i have added some information hope thats sufficient

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, a BufferedWriter by itself does not 'require' getters.

If your BufferedWriter is not writing data, then the problem might be how you are actually writing the data. You also might want to check if you are calling `.close()` when you are done writing the data.

Another problem might be how your data is returned from the get-er.

*Edit:
Thank you for updating your question. 
If you want to write out the details of `character_Class`, you do need to call the getters of the specific information that you want to get from the class.

The reason why `bufWrite.write("Your Character Class:" + character_Class + "\n");` doesn't throw an exception or crash is because of how java coerces classes to String.

The line of code: 
`"Your Character Class:" + character_Class`
is the same as: 
`"Your Character Class:" + character_Class.toString()`

Same happens with objects from skillInfo:
`bufWrite.write("" + o.toString() + "-  Rank(skill Points) :" + rank);`

Basically, if you concatenate '+' a String and an object, it calls toString() on the object. If you concatenate a String and a primitive type, it just converts them to Strings first.

Comment: HI , thank you so much for your input, I have used the ..close() and the case is some data is written while a selected amount is not . And the only connection i could find was that the data that is not written comes from the same class as the BufferedWriter is in.Therefor the only difference i could find was that everything that is written has something to catch the data entered by the use except the ones i have listen above.